# Solving a limit for capacity of a transmission system

Tags: calculus, limits, dynamical-systems

I'm studying dynamical systems and I've found myself trying to solve this limit:

$$ \lim_{k \to +\infty} \frac{\log_{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^k - \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^k)}{k}$$

Till now, I changed the base of the logarithm and converted it to a natural logarithm:

$$ \frac{1}{\ln(2)} \lim_{k \to +\infty} \frac{\ln(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^k - \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^k)}{k}$$

But I'm not sure how should I continue. I know that the result is $$\frac{\ln(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})}{\ln(2)}$$

Thanks!

Comment: The term within the logarithm is dominated by the $\phi^k$ part because the latter term tend to zero. Hence the limit comes from applying the regular logarithm laws on the asymptotic expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
&\frac{ \ln\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left( \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^k  -  \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left( \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^k \right) }{k}  \\
&\qquad = \frac{ \ln\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left( \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^k \left( 1  -  \left( \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{1+\sqrt{5}} \right)^k \right) \right) }{k}  \\
&\qquad = \frac{ \ln\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left( \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^k \right) + \ln \left( 1  -  \left( \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{1+\sqrt{5}} \right)^k \right)}{k}  \\
&\qquad = \frac{ \ln\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \right) + k \ln \left( \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}  \right) + \ln \left( 1  -  \left( \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{1+\sqrt{5}} \right)^k \right)}{k}  \\
&\qquad = \ln \left( \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}  \right) + \frac{ \ln\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \right) + \ln \left( 1  -  \left( \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{1+\sqrt{5}} \right)^k \right)}{k}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
The first term is a constant, so survives the limit.  In the numerator, the first term is a constant, and the second term goes to $\ln 1 = 0$ because $-1 < \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{1 + \sqrt{5}} < 1$, so its $k^\text{th}$ power goes to $0$.  That is, the wide fraction on the right vanishes in the limit.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Binet's formula for the Fibonacci numbers is
$$F_n=\frac{\phi^n-{\tilde{\phi}}^n}{\sqrt{5}}$$
Here $\phi=(1=\sqrt{5})/2$ and $\tilde{\phi}=(1-\sqrt{5})/2$

So,
$$L=\frac{1}{\ln(2)}\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\ln(F_k)}{k}$$
But we know that $F_k\asymp \phi^k$,
$$L=\frac{1}{\ln(2)}\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\ln(\phi^k)}{k}=\frac{1}{\ln(2)}\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{k\ln(\phi)}{k}=\frac{\ln(\phi)}{\ln(2)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

A variation on @Eric Towers solution, for the last term, you can use Maclaurin series for the logarithm function expansion around $0$ after noticing that the term $a^k \to 0$:
$$
\frac{\log (1-a^k)}{k} \sim -\frac{a^k}{k} \to0< s_k < \frac{\log (1+a^k)}{k} \sim \frac{a^k}{k} \to0
$$
where $a_k = \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{1+\sqrt{5}}$